# Reporting ties for position n in the list of most frequent occurring words

Tags: java

Hi all I have a problem with printing tied position in Java,
for instance I have printed n frequently occurring words in Java but found if **there are ties at nth position**  the program should report all the ties at that position alone.

My code fails with that as it reports only n frequently occurring words with the count
not more than n even if there is a tie.
Here is my snippet:

```
.....
.....

Collections.sort(newList, new Words());

int j = 0;
for (Words w : newList.subList(0, 20)) {
    System.out.println("Word : " + ++j + " " + w.getWord() + " " + w.getCount());
}

fileReader.close();
```

My output is something like this :

```
input is a set of 5 files 

.....
.....
.....
Word : 17 another 340
Word : 18 nothing 339
Word : 19 father 313
Word : 20 should 306
```

for 306 position there are 2 more words with the same count but they are not getting reported how can i make my code to get my result !

Comment: Can you add an example for input output strings?

Comment: Why not just use Map<String, Integer>? It's not the best solution in terms of space complexity, but it would make the algorithm much easier to write.

Comment: @0x90   I have added them in edit pls check it

Comment: In your debugger did you inspect the contents of "newList"?  You did not explain the reason for subList.  A subList means you are filtering out data which is what your question is about.  A runnable example should be provided.  What does .close() have to do with this?  [Please follow mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).